# Interesting observation with BitConverter.GetBytes() in Compact Framework

Tags: c#, compact-framework, arrays, bitconverter

I am trying to convert a float value to byte array using BitConverter.GetBytes(...) method. I came across one interesting issue. Consider following code -

```
float f = 0.0;
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(f);
for (int j = 0; j < bytes.Length; j++)
{
     Trace.Write(bytes [j] + " ");
}
```

Above conversion returns array of 4 bytes which I am printing on console. However, i noticed that sometimes the output of 4 bytes is {0 0 0 128} instead of {0 0 0 0}.

Any help?

Thanks,
Omky

Comment: So you have discovered the existance of negative zero in floating points :-) :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero

> The IEEE 754 standard for floating point arithmetic (presently used by most computers and programming languages that support floating point numbers) requires both +0 and −0

What you have found is the negative zero.